# How to decrease logging level reported in Console?

Tags: macos, console

I think my macOS works in some debug mode, but I'm not sure, because when I open *Console*, I see a lot of log entries every second, despite not doing much. If I enabled that mode, I don't remember how it was enabled. There are some entries regarding memory allocation,  and some other.

Before I didn't see so much logs, unless it's a Sierra thing.

I don't have any extras in `boot-args` section when running: `nvram -p`.

Here is the example:

[image: Console macOS logs]

How do I lower the verbosity of my logs? Or such thing is expected?

I'm aware that I can filter the logs by choosing *Errors and Faults*, but this is not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

No, reducing verboseness of the macOS logs is not a standard option.

While there may be a Terminal command/flag or a mod GUI app that lets you change the error levels recorded, I'd advise against doing so because if and when you need support/help, the console logs will be one of the places a tech person would review, and if they're truncated then there's less clues for the person investigating an issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the system-wide logging settings with `log(1)`.

```
sudo log config --mode "level: error"
```

…should limit logging to error-level messages only.

I have not tested this, and I would advise against it.  Rather use the `log` command in collaboration with the Console application to filter only the messages you want to see.

Answer (score 0):

I also experience this and most of the log messages look completely uninteresting and I am wondering if that write operations are bad for the flash storage in the long run...